# How to execute separate process in PHP

Tags: php, process, exec

I want to run service in PHP which to be run in the background. I have tried by using `exec()` function in PHP but service is being run in infinite loop and control is not returning back over PHP file. I have searched more over the internet but I can't find the solution. Please give me some idea or reference to achieve this task.

This is code for reference what I want to do:-

```
echo"hello";
exec("raintree.frm");
echo"hello1";
```

`raintree.frm` is a service which I want to execute. Here PHP script prints "hello" over browser but that is not coming on "hello1" because control gets stuck on `exec()` function.

Comment: That means `raintree.frm` is doing it's thing.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php: "If a program is started with [exec], in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends."

Comment: For some code, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101506 and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#107456

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to have your service running in a separate process, as the title states, you need to create the new process and then run the service in it. In PHP you can create a new process with [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) and start the service in the child process. Something like this

```php
echo "hello";
$pid = pcntl_fork();
switch($pid){
    case -1:    // pcntl_fork() failed
        die('could not fork');
    case 0:    // you're in the new (child) process
        exec("raintree.frm");
        // controll goes further down ONLY if exec() fails
        echo 'exec() failed';
    default:  // you're in the main (parent) process in which the script is running
        echo "hello1";
}
```

For more clarification read the manual (the link above to `pcntl_fork()`) as well as look at some C/Unix tutorials on the topics (or rather syscalls) `fork()` and `exec()`.

Comment: Great, simple example of `pcntl_fork` that I found useful as I didn't even have to grab the php manual for. Thanks!

Comment: This code is not working as expected. `default` case will be executed twice. You need to add `break` statements inside every `case`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `atd` for running arbitrary commands in a separate process:

```
shell_exec('echo code you want to run | at -m now');
```

For this, `atd` should be installed and running, of course.

Comment: Thanks - this is pretty elegant for systems that support `atd`

Answer (score -2):

The `exec()` function is waiting to receive the output of the externally executed command.

To prevent this from happening, you can redirect the output elsewhere:

```
<?php

echo 'hello1';
exec('raintree.frm > /dev/null &');
echo 'hello2';
```

This example will output "hello1hello2" without waiting for `raintree.frm > /dev/null &` to finish.

(this probably only works with Unix-like operating systems)